# Logback logging levels are ignored, Spring Boot 2.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I have been using logback successfully for a while in my Spring Boot applications using Spring Boot 1.5.x and 2.1.x. I use logback-spring.xml on the classpath to configure logback.

After a recent build using Spring Boot version 2.1.0.BUILD_SNAPSHOT, the output to my logs suddenly changed. I am now getting all DEBUG and TRACE levels on all packages (other than my own) e.g. on startup I am swamped with org.apache.* and org.springframework.* logging.

When I try to adjust the logging levels for these packages, the levels are ignored. I.e. the following does not work in limiting the logging:

```
<logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR"/>    
<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
```

- Adjusting the logging level of the root logger also has no affect.
- I have ensured that debug=false in application.properties
- Note that the log levels for my application still work.

  ```
  <logger name="com.myapp" level="debug">
     <appender-ref ref="MY_FILE" />
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />   
  </logger>
  ```

So it appears that my configuration is indeed found and used to configure logback, but the logging levels for some packages are broken or being overridden?

I have just tested with Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE and I do not have the problem with this version.

Comment: i have the exact same problem with Spring Boot 2.0.3 and i have not been able to resolve it

Comment: Same problem with 2.1.0.M2

Comment: Added an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14310

Comment: Having the same issue with Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE

Comment: facing same issue